# Couchbase in Spring with default values when saving

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We're using Couchbase database and Springboot, and we are facing an issue: we'd like to set a default value for a param of our model when it is going to be saved in database (as long as it hasn't already been set).

Our model is something like:

```
@Document
class Book {

...

@Field("quantity")
int quantity;

...

int getQuantity() {return quantity;}

void setQuantity(int quantity){this.quantity = quantity;}

...

}
```

So, how could I set a default value **without using a default constructor** or **setting the default value when defining the variable**?

Thanks a lot